# Ruby version syntax

Tags: ruby, scripting

What's the naming syntax for different versions of ruby and which should I gravitate towards for running scripts? i.e., using rbenv I can install the following versions of Ruby 1.9.3:

```
1.9.3-dev
1.9.3-p0
1.9.3-p125
1.9.3-p194
1.9.3-p286
1.9.3-p327
1.9.3-p362
1.9.3-p374
1.9.3-p385
1.9.3-p392
1.9.3-p429
1.9.3-preview1
1.9.3-rc1
```

So we have several different types:

- dev
- p#
- preview#
- rc#

I believe I can assume that `p#` is for build fixes to the spec, `preview#` is a preview of the version spec and a precursor to `rc#`, the release candidate of the spec. So, this leaves `dev`. Is the `dev` tagged build what I should use for scripting or is it the development branch? And should I try to keep the latest `p#` installed? What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby uses [semver](http://semver.org/) for naming versions.

Best practice is keep your ruby as up-to-date as possible using the latest `p#` build.

Current version is Ruby `2.0.0-p195`

If you're stuck in 1.9.3 for compatibility reasons, the latest patch is `1.9.3-p459`.

You can see these versions on the [Ruby homepage](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)

Comment: Note that while Ruby *does* use a form of semantic versioning, it *does not* use the *exact* form described at [Semantic Versioning](http://SemVer.Org/). SemVer describes a *three-part* versioning scheme `X.Y.Z` where `X` is the major version, `Y` is the minor version and `Z` is the patch-level. Ruby has a *four-part* version number `W.X.Y-pZ` where `X` is the *minor version* (but corresponds to SemVer's *major version*), `Y` is the *tiny version* (but corresponds to SemVer's *minor version*), and `Z` is *patch level*. `W` is the *major version* and it has no correspondence in SemVer. …

Comment: … It is used for "epochal" changes. For example, the jump from `1` to `2` was made for Ruby's 20th birthday, not for any particular set of features. If Ruby sometime in the future were to gain a static type system that would probably warrant a 3.

Comment: FWIW, Ruby only started using semantic versioning as of 2.1: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/.