# Ruby version syntax, x.x.x-dev, preview, rc, what is the oldest and newest?

Tags: ruby

I want to ask about naming convention of ruby version.

According to [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993583/ruby-version-syntax) ruby follows `Semantic Versioning`, but I could not find about `x.x.x-dev` and `x.x.x-preview` syntax in the document.

I think `dev` comes first and then `preview`, and at last `rc` comes up.
Do you know where is the ruby official document that explains about their versioning convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is documented somewhere, however these are the most common conventions used in the Ruby core development

- `dev` means the development version. It's the first stage, no public release. Normally you can download a night build or snapshot
- `preview` is also what other projects normally call `beta` release.
- `rc` is the release candidate, very close to the release
- finally, you have the stable release